# Trying to filter this mapping of cryptocurrencies by name. Why does the code below not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Essentially on submit of the form I would like to take this value and pass it into the currencies.filter function. Where it says document.getElementById...

When it is

currency.currency === 'BTC'

this works

however this does not

currency.currency === document.getElementById('userInput')

Even better would be to filter the form real time as I am typing, but this seems quite challenging for me.

Thanks

```
import React  from 'react'
import { withRouteData, Link } from 'react-static'
//
export default withRouteData(({ currencies }) => (
<div> 

  <Link to="/">Quoinex</Link>
  <Link to="/qryptos"><b>Qryptos</b></Link>
  <form id="form" onSubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="BTC etc." id="userInput"/>
    <input className="sub" type="submit" onClick="othername();" />
  </form>
  <h1>Tokens</h1>
  <br />
  <table className="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Crypto/Token</th>
      <th>Min Withdrawal Qty</th>
      <th>Min Order Qty</th>
    </tr>
    { currencies.filter(currency => currency.currency === document.getElementById('userInput')).map(currency => (
      <tr key={currency.currency}>
        <td id="tokenName">{currency.currency}</td>
        <td>{currency.minimum_withdrawal}</td>
        <td>{currency.minimum_order_quantity}</td> 
      </tr>
    ))}
  </table>

</div>
))
```

Comment: The problem is that by comparing `currency.currency === document.getElementById('userInput')` you compare currency value vs element you retrieved. Try `currency.currency === document.getElementById('userInput').value`

Answer (score 0):

The `Document` method `getElementById()` returns an Element object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string. (Taken from MDN)

hence, this is a normal Javascript object, in order to get the input actual value you need to refer to

```
document.getElementById('userInput').value
```